# How do I pass the value from a foreach loop to an add_filter function?

Tags: filters

I'm trying to add multiple filters from inside a foreach loop. Unfortunately I can't get the code to reference the value properly. How do I pass the value from the loop to the function?

The following sets all the filters to null.

```
foreach ( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
     add_filter( "plugin_filter_$key", function( $value ) { return $value; } );
}
```

This is my test code and this sets the filters to 'true'.

```
foreach ( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
     add_filter( "plugin_filter_$key", function( $value ) { return 'true'; } );
}
```

Comment: True, your use case is WordPress ... but this is a vanilla PHP loop/closure question. Closing as off-topic, but not migrating since you've already got an answer.

Comment: Well I didn't know that when I asked it. Far as I knew, my issue could have revolved around my usage of add_filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
     add_filter( "plugin_filter_$key", function () use ( $value ) { return $value; } );
}
```

Check out [the `use` keyword for closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-us).

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!!